# How to get Btrfs verify checksum for one file?

Tags: filesystems, btrfs, checksum, data-integrity

Btrfs offers these commands to verify data integrity/checksums:

```
btrfs scrub start <path>|<device>
btrfs check --check-data-csum
```

However, AFAIK those always verify *whole* filesystems; the `path` argument is to identify a filesystem on a device, not file/directory within filesystem.

Now, I have a 3TB Btrfs filesystem. Scrubbing it takes hours. Sometimes I need to make sure that only certain file/directory has not yet been affected by bitrot — for example, before using an *.iso installation image or restoring a backup. **How do I use Btrfs for this** — without falling back to keeping manual hash files per each file?

I am aware that Btrfs does not store checksums for individual files — it stores checksums for *blocks of data*. In this case what I am looking for is a command/tool that identifies all the blocks used for storing certain files/directories and verifies those blocks only.

I read somewhere that Btrfs allegedly verifies checksums *on read*. That is, if a file has been bit-rotted, reading it would fail or something like that. Is this the case?

Comment: Do you regularly have a problem with files becoming corrupted? That's not normal, I'd suspect a bad drive or ram first, maybe bad filesystem drivers second. Instead of keeping hashes or checksums in a separate database to verify files, you could keep files in an archive that stores a checksum itself, and would save some space too.

Comment: @Xen2050 no, no problems so far, just want to be able to get 100% confidence. Archives with built-in checksums are an option, but I'd like to employ Btrfs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is: simply **try reading the whole file**. If it reads differently from what has been checksummed, there will be an **Input/output error**. So yes, Btrfs indeed verifies checksums on read!

To find out this answer, I put together the following test:

1. Allocate a 1 Gb file to be used as a block device for testing Btrfs partition, mount it as a loop device and format Btrfs on it;
2. Create a dummy 800 Mb file containing a known unique sequence of bytes in the middle (`token1`);
3. Write the file to the Btrfs and record its sha256 for later reference;
4. Unmount and patch the block device file so that one byte is changed. For this, we `sed`-replace `token1` with `token2`;
5. Mount again and try getting sha256 of the 800 Mb file on the Btrfs. See Input/output error;
6. Unmount, patch back, mount and see that the 800 Mb file is readable again and sha256 is the same as in step 3;
7. Profit!

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
f="btrfstestblockdevicefile"
ft="btrfstestfile"
loop="/dev/loop0"
mount_dir="btrfstestdir"
size="1g"
token1="36bbf48aa6645646fbaa7f25b64224fb3399ad40bc706c79bb8276096e3c9e8f"
token2="36bbf48aa6645646fbaa7f25b64224fb4399ad40bc706c79bb8276096e3c9e8f"

f_mount() {
    echo "Mounting..." && \
    sudo losetup $loop $f && \
    if ! [[ -z $1 ]] ; then
        sudo mkfs.btrfs -q $loop
    fi
    mkdir $mount_dir && \
    sudo mount $loop $mount_dir
}

f_umount() {
    echo "Unmounting..." && \
    sudo umount $loop && \
    sudo rmdir $mount_dir && \
    sudo losetup -d $loop
}

echo "Allocating file for test block device..." && \
fallocate -l $size $f && \
f_mount 1 && \
echo "Generating test file..." && \
dd if=/dev/urandom of="${ft}1" bs=1M count=400 status=none && \
echo $token1 > "${ft}2" && \
dd if=/dev/urandom of="${ft}3" bs=1M count=400 status=none && \
sudo sh -c "cat ${ft}1 ${ft}2 ${ft}3 > ${mount_dir}/${ft}" && \
rm "${ft}1" "${ft}2" "${ft}3" && \
echo "Calculating original hash of the file..." && \
sha256sum "${mount_dir}/${ft}" && \
f_umount && \
echo "Patching the file in the block device file..." && \
sed -i "s/${token1}/${token2}/g" $f && sync && \
f_mount && \
echo "Trying to read the file..." && \
sha256sum "${mount_dir}/${ft}"
echo "OK, unmount, patch back and try again..." && \
f_umount && \
sed -i "s/${token2}/${token1}/g" $f && sync && \
f_mount && \
sha256sum "${mount_dir}/${ft}" && \
echo "Yay, Btrfs rules! Cleaning up..." && \
f_umount && \
rm $f && \
echo "All clear!"
```

As expected, replacing `mkfs.btrfs` with making a non-checksumming filesystem (e.g. `mkfs.ext4`) allows for the corrupted file to be read. Of course, its sha256 is different from the non-corrupted one.